# Failing to sign embedded frameworks (cocoapods) xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'll try to be as concise as possible but feel free to ask for further details.

First of all, on both machines code signing passes and there are no errors at any point in Xcode. When archiving app and exporting ipa on my MacBookPro the app successfully installs and runs on a device. When doing the same on our CI server (manually via Aqua session, not through a script) the app installs but crashes as soon as the app references any library with the following error: `kernel(AppleMobileFileIntegrity)[0] <Error>: Library Validation failed: Rejecting '' (Team ID: , platform: ) for process '(<decode failure invalid size>)' (Team ID: <private>, platform: <missing data>), reason: <missing data>`.

The only difference between server and my Mac configuration is that server runs on El Capitan and I've updated to Sierra.

Configuration:
Cocoapods v. 1.1.1

XCode v. 8.1 (8B62)

Provisioning profile permission: Enterprise distribution

OS versions are in discrepancy (read above)

I've searched a couple of days for the solution and didn't find anyone having the same problem, let alone solution for it. I've probably tried all that you are going to suggest, but I'm still hoping someone has a solution to propose without updating server to Sierra.

Comment: Do you version your pods or does your CI server `pod install`?

Comment: Regardless of the CI pipeline, the app crashes even when it's built manually on the Mac we're using as CI server. As for the Pod project configurations they're empty (no signing and no team development id)